# Project Naptha recreation in Python

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

## **Goal:**

I am trying to recreate Project Naptha. It is a Chrome extension that allows you to select and copy text from any image inside your browser. I want to replicate that functionality across my entire computer and all my apps using Python.

## **Current progress:**

This is my code for OCR in an image:

```
import pyautogui, keyboard, pytesseract, cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Local\Programs\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

print("Press s to save position of first top-left corner of the screenshot.")
keyboard.wait("s")
x1, y1 = pyautogui.position()
print("Press s to save position of second bottom-right corner of the screenshot.")
keyboard.wait("s")
x2, y2 = pyautogui.position()

img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x1, y1, x2 - 280, y2 - 160))
#img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang="eng")
print("Recognition process done. Dumping into image_text.txt ...")

with open("image_text.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(img_text)
```

The program saves the top-left and bottom-right corners when *s* is pressed, then takes a screenshot of the area and extracts the text from it. At the end, the program exports it into a text file.

**Targeted result:**
I want the program to automatically scan the screen for text and make it highlightable. When it is highlighted and ctrl+c is pressed, the text gets copied to the clipboard.

Comment: And what happens when you run this?  Do you get results?  There are far better ways to extract text from local applications, by querying the window structure of the applications.  What you're doing is always going to be an approximation.

Comment: The code works, but my goal is to get system-wide text detection (as described above). I am interested in how to implement the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Well, `pytesseract.image_to_boxes` will return to you the locations as well as the text, but remember that onscreen text changes quickly.  It might be a better experience if you just displayed the text you grabbed and let the user select and copy from that.